# Find unique values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like the following one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 1
                )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array 
                (
                   [0] => 3
                   [1] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array 
                (
                   [0] => 4
                   [1] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array 
                (
                   [0] => 5
                   [1] => 2
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 2
                )
        )

...

)
```

I'd like to remove the duplicate fields and have unique values inside each `array()` that composes the "big array".

For example: the `$array[0]` has inside the value `(3,1) ($array[0][1])`, this value `(2,0)` is also found in `$array[1][0]`, so I want to delete both of them.

The array I've posted above should return the following one after that procedure

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 0
                )


    [1] => Array
        (

            [1] => Array 
                (
                   [0] => 4
                   [1] => 2
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 1
                )
        )

...

)
```

Is there any useful function that helps? How can I solve this?

Comment: What about http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: I would feel quite stupid if this works ;)

Comment: It doens't work as expected since this is a multidimensional array :(

Comment: Why not parse it as a matrix and check individual elements, which are actually arrays? Removing duplicates from matrices should be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a php function for this. But you could try something like this:

```
$array = array(array(array(2,0),array(3,1)),array(array(3,1),array(4,2),array(5,2)),array(array(2,1),array(5,2)));


$newArray = array();

foreach($array as $innerArray){                 //Write all the innermost arrays into one array
    foreach($innerArray as $innerMostArray){
        $newArray[] = $innerMostArray;
    }
}

$uniqueArrays = array();
$duplicateArrays = array();

foreach($newArray as $key => $innerArray){          //Search for unique arrays in $newArray
    unset($newArray[$key]);

    if(!in_array($innerArray,$duplicateArrays)){ //If array is already in duplicate arrays, just ignore it
        if(in_array($innerArray,$newArray)){
            $duplicateArrays[] = $innerArray;
        }else{
            $uniqueArrays[] = $innerArray;
        }
    }
}

unset($duplicateArrays);
unset($newArray);

$newArray = array();

foreach($array as $innerArray){ //Rebuild the structure of the old array
    $newInnerArray = array();

    foreach($uniqueArrays as $uniqueArray){
        $key = array_search($uniqueArray,$innerArray);

        if($key !== false){ //Only write the unique arrays into the new array
            $newInnerArray[$key] = $uniqueArray; //preserve the old key
            unset($uniqueArrays[$key]);
        }
    }

    if(count($newInnerArray) != 0){
        $newArray[] = $newInnerArray;
    }
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at array_unique() function.. It will point out the unique in each function..

or otherwise

array_diff() one another to see the differences